# How do i convert a unix timestamp to a UTC date string on chain?

Tags: rust

I don't think the chrono package is able to be used?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I can't think of a scenario in which it is necessary

Comment: To store expiry timestamp as a metadata string

Comment: In general, best practices with timestamps is to work with them entirely as numbers until they finally need to be displayed in UI, in which case you can convert to whatever string representation is appropriate. Working with timestamp strings on-chain is not preferable because the string conversion is expensive, you can't do math on them, and they are less efficient to store. I also can't think of a scenario in which all of this added burden is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Although I believe the advice you got in the comments is correct and you shouldn't convert to UTC unless to display in the UI, I hate answers that just say "Why would you do that?" instead of answering. So here's how to convert to from a UNIX timestamp to UTC without chrono:

```
fn unix_timestamp_to_utc_date(unix_timestamp: u64) -> String {
    let epoch_year = 1970;
    let epoch_days = 365 * (epoch_year - 1) + (epoch_year - 1) / 4 - (epoch_year - 1) / 100 + (epoch_year - 1) / 400;

    let seconds_in_a_day = 24 * 60 * 60;

    let days = (unix_timestamp / seconds_in_a_day) + epoch_days;
    let seconds_remainder = unix_timestamp % seconds_in_a_day;

    let hours = seconds_remainder / 3600;
    let minutes = (seconds_remainder % 3600) / 60;
    let seconds = seconds_remainder % 60;

    format!("{:04}-{:02}-{:02} {:02}:{:02}:{:02}", epoch_year, 1, days, hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```